# I have heard about “in/on the news”. What about “at the news”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I know that we commonly use “on the news” or “in the news”. However, I came across a sentence which is:

> - They were overcome by a wave of horror **at the news**.

As far as I can understand is that “at” in this context is referring to a specific piece of news.

Though, is “at the news” interchangeably used with **on the news**, or it has a different meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"In the news" means that a subject is currently found *across all news media* - on TV or radio news broadcasts, or in newspapers etc.

> eg "The story has been in the news this week".

"On the news" would be used to refer to a *specific* news broadcast or source.

> eg "I saw it on the news last night".

Your example using "at the news" could refer to hearing "news" from *any* source, not necessarily "news media". It could equally apply if an individual told you something important to you personally but not "newsworthy" to anyone else.

> They reeled in horror at the news that their aunt had died.

It means that they reacted *upon hearing* whatever they have been told. You could not interchangeably use "at" with any of the other examples using "in/on".